# Looping through an array assigning values to anchor links

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that looks like this
`["1352.jpg", "1353.jpg", "1354"]`. I want to loop through this array and render anchor links of items comma-separated. I am looking at something like this, `<a href='1352.jpg'>1352.jpg</a>, <a href='1353.jpg'>1353.jpg</a>, etc`. I can't seem to get this to work. This is what I am doing but I am not getting what I want.

```
var images = ["1352.jpg", "1353.jpg", "1354"];
renderImages(images){
        var result;
        if(images != null && images.length > 0){
            result = images.map(obj => {
                var res = '<a href='+obj+'>obj</a>';
            });
            result = res.join(', ');
        }else{
             result = 'null';
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Please what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't surround `obj` with `'` in the innertext, you are just setting it as obj, is that what you are missing? and you are not returning anything from your map arrow function, so it will be undefined instead

Comment: You tagged the question with React? Why are you building HTML strings?

Comment: Also, what is not working? Please provide a [mcve], the expected behaviour and describe the currently incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use string interpolation, your original code was missing the return inside the map function, and you had `obj` directly written in the inner tag

```
var images = ["1352.jpg", "1353.jpg", "1354"];
renderImages(images){
    if(!images || !images.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return images.map(obj => `<a href='${obj}'>${obj}</a>`);
}
```

I am also wondering if you intend to return the textual version of `null` or just `null` so in my answer I returned `null` instead.

Having seen the comment from Emile, you did indeed tag it with [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), in that case, you should probably just render jsx nodes instead, which you could do like:

```
return (
  <div>
    { images && images.length && images.map( img => <a key={img} href={img}>{img}</a> ) 
  </div> );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const images = ['image1_url', 'image2_url', 'image3_url']
const app = document.getElementById('app');

function renderImages() {
    return images.map((link) => {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', link);
        a.innerText = link;
        a.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', ', ');
        app.appendChild(a);
    });
```

}

```
renderImages()
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing that comes to mind is the missing return statement here:

```
images.map(obj => {
            var res = '<a href='+obj+'>obj</a>';
           return res;
        });
```

or just remove {} and variable declaration.

```
images.map(obj => '<a href='+obj+'>obj</a>');
```

Then change 
`result = res.join(", ");` 
to 
`result = result.join(", ");`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const imageHrefs = ["1352.jpg", "1353.jpg", "1354.png"];
const container = document.getElementById('container');

imageHrefs.forEach((href) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', href);
  a.innerText = `Link to ${href}`;
  container.appendChild(a);
  container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
})
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

You can also use a different solution, other than using `.map()`.

Answer (score -1):

This works, just made a little adjustment to your map and join statement.

```js
var images = ["1352.jpg", "1353.jpg", "1354"];
function renderImages(images) {
        var result;
        if(images != null && images.length > 0){
            result = images.map(obj => {
                return '<a href='+obj+'>obj</a>';
            });
            result = result.join(', ');
        }else{
             result = 'null';
        }
        return result;
    }

list = renderImages(images)
console.log(list)
```